# Extract Rows from different df`s

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So I'm trying to extract the number of rows from two datasets that are between -20 to -15 and between -15 to -5 and between -5 and 5.

eg. the dfne dataframe

```
        Latitude  Longitude  Altitude     Value     O18nd
0           30.0      -30.0       0.0 -3.776897 -3.776897
1           30.0      -29.9       0.0 -3.765203 -3.765203
2           30.0      -29.8       0.0 -3.753469 -3.753469
3           30.0      -29.7       0.0 -3.741694 -3.741694
4           30.0      -29.6       0.0 -3.729879 -3.729879
...          ...        ...       ...       ...       ...
359995      69.9       59.5      68.0 -8.602635 -8.738635
359996      69.9       59.6      74.0 -8.594053 -8.742053
359997      69.9       59.7      52.0 -8.585532 -8.689532
```

I would then like to create a database that is structured as follows (example data)
[image]

For this I have written the following code, but I do not know how to extract this data range

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as scs
from Extract_elevation import *

dfe = dfle  #daten alt
dfne = dflne    #daten neu 


dfn= dfne.loc[dfne.O18nd == '-20', 'O18nd'].count()
dfa = dfle.loc[dfle.O18ad == '-20', 'O18ad'].count()

df = pd.DataFrame({
   'old' : dfa,
   'new' : dfn,
});
```

Comment: Why are you not getting the values from the input data?

Comment: Yeah I want the same bin count

Comment: But how do you do this? I tried it earlier

Comment: edit your post and include the code that you tried with

Comment: I deletet it: my problem was i want the  data range between -20 an -15 hoever I can only count: dfne.loc[dfne.O18nd == '-20', 'O18nd'].count()

Comment: I'm sorry but you'll need to update your post with the code that you have tried, being clear about what you're trying to achieve. You've only posted code for creating the plot itself.

Comment: Ok I changed it! Hope It make my question clear :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first strategy i thought of is just to perform filtering using `pandas.query` method.

```
dfn = dfne.query('O18nd >= -20').query('O18nd <= -10') ['O18nd'].count()
```

In this example, you get count values for the interval [-20 , -10].

You can automatize the procedure by using groupby and apply count operation on these cut range of values:

```
tmp = dfne.groupby(pd.cut(dfne["O18nd"], np.arange(-20, 10, 5)))['O18nd'].count()
dfa = pd.DataFrame(tmp).rename(columns={'O18nd': 'O18nd_count_a'})
```

You will get a result dataframe with a row for each value range:

```
            O18nd_count
O18nd                   
(-20, -15]  2
(-15, -10]  1
...
(5, 10]    2
```

(the values are just random).

If you want both two dataframes, you can just apply a join based on the `O18nd` column (after a reset_index).

```
df_final = pd.merge(dfe, dfa, on=['O18nd'])
```

Comment: how can I combine this in one dataframe?

Comment: using the final merge.